# Raspberry Pi 3 with Feetech FS90R servo

Tags: rpi.gpio, windows-iot

Currently I have a very basic setup where I have a FS90R continuous servo running on a my Raspberry Pi 3 using Windows IoT and a C# based application.

I'm trying to get the servo to pin using the below code which is trigger every 10 seconds however the servo doesn't seem to react.

```
            if (SRpin.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low)
            SRpin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        else
            SRpin.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
```

I have tested other components like an LED with success and the servo does work as it turns when i first plug in the live cable.

Currently the live cable in plugged into the 5V output.

I have declared the servo pin using the GpioController and set the servo pin as an output device with a default GpioPinValue of Low.

Is there possibly anything else I can check to get this servo to spin correctly?

Once I can get it to spin, I'll start adding PWM etc.

Comment: The requirement is PWN from the start. Continuous rotation means it can rotate past 360 degrees and can continue indefinitely.  Welcome to the Pi Q&A though. Please up vote and accept answers that are helpful especially go and use the search functionality. There is a ton of great material here that should get you going. If for whatever reason you get stuck with PWM on IoT try another question please.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a continuous rotation servo is just a modified standard servo.

A normal servo takes pulses (typically 50 times per second) of between 1 and 2 ms in length.  One extreme moves the servo to a fixed position clockwise, the other to a fixed position counterclockwise.  Pulse lengths between those values move the servo to a proportionate position.

Continuous servos also need pulses (again typically 50 times per second) of between 1 and 2 ms.  One extreme rotates the servo at a fixed high speed clockwise, the other at a fixed high speed counterclockwise.    Pulse lengths between those values move the servo at a proportionate speed.  Pulses of 1.5 ms in length should stop the servo.

In short, nothing will happen until you generate PWM at 50 Hz with an appropriate pulse length.